# What does it mean if ROC curves (training ROCs) are very smooth?

Tags: r, machine-learning, roc

I am a beginner to statistical / machine learning modelling and have a beginner question.

What does it mean if ROC curves are very smooth? That is they actually look like curves.

In textbooks, these curves usually have more angles and steep increases.

I hope you get what I mean.

Best,
corkinabottle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you have many test cases, or that you are using software that does smoothing. It also means you have a test result that is continuous rather than categorical.